# Convert java.lang.reflect.Type to Class<T> clazz

Tags: java, generics

How can I convert `java.lang.reflect.Type` to `Class<T> clazz`?

If I have one method as next which has an argument of `Class<T>`:

```
public void oneMethod(Class<T> clazz) {     
    //Impl
}
```

Then another method which has an argument of `java.lang.reflect.Type` and it calls `oneMethod(Class<T> clazz)` and for it I need to convert `java.lang.reflect.Type type`  to `Class<T>`:

```
public void someMehtod(java.lang.reflect.Type type) {
   // I want to pass type arg to other method converted in Class<T>
   otherMethod(¿How to convert java.lang.reflect.Type to Class<T>?);
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have to ensure that `type` is an instance of `Class`, and then cast it.

```
if (type instanceof Class) {
  Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) type;
  otherMethod(clazz);
}
```

Of course, you also have to handle the case of it not being a `Class`.

Answer (score 25):

If you are willing to use a library, you could use `com.google.guava:guava:12+`:

```
Class<?> clazz = com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.of(type).getRawType();
```

Alternatively you could also use `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.x`:

```
Class<?> clazz = com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.rawClass(type);
```

This handles all cases correctly and you will get the type-erased class of your type.

Answer (score 3):

Using generic types in runtime is a little bit tricky in Java. And I think this is a root cause of your issue.

1) to be sure about generic in runtime we doing like this:

```
class MyClass<E> {}
```

and then:

```
MyClass<TargetType> genericAwaredMyClassInctance = new MyClass<TargetType>(){};
```

**please pay attention to {} in the end**. It means anonymous extends of MyClass. This is an important nuance.

2) let`s improve MyClass to be able to extract the  type in runtime.

```
class MyClass<E> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected Class<E> getGenericClass() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Type mySuperclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        Type tType = ((ParameterizedType)mySuperclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        String className = tType.getTypeName();

        return (Class<E>) Class.forName(className);
    }

}
```

and finally, use it like this:

```
MyClass<TargetType> genericAwaredMyClassInctance = new MyClass<TargetType>(){};

assert(genericAwaredMyClassInctance.getGenericClass() == TargetType.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Andy Turner answer is correct, however if you need to retrieve a class from a type parameter this is a complete example:

```
private static class MyClass extends ArrayList<Integer> {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ParameterizedType arrayListWithParamType
            = (ParameterizedType) MyClass.class.getGenericSuperclass();

    Type integerType = arrayListWithParamType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

    Class<?> integerClass = (Class<?>) integerType;

    System.out.println(integerClass == Integer.class);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

It would be weird that a `Type` would be anything else than a `Class`... Javadoc for `Type` says

> All Known Implementing Classes:
>       Class

So unless you have special libraries that use non `Class` `Type`s, you can simply cast - but you must be ready for a possible `ClassCastException`. 
Beware: Java use undocumented Type implementation to represent generics, see below.

You can explicitely process it or not because it is an unchecked exception:

Explicit way:

```
try {
    Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) type;
}
catch (ClassCastException ex) {
    // process exception
}
```

Implicit way:

```
Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) type;
```

but the current method could throw...

---

EDIT per @Andy Turner's comment:

Beware: `Type type = new ArrayList<String>().getClass().getGenericSuperclass();` yields something that's a Type but not a Class. This one is a `ParameterizedType`, so you can use `getRawType()` method to find the actual class, but others might exist.

Comment: e.g. `Type type = new ArrayList<String>().getClass().getGenericSuperclass();` yields something that's a `Type` but not a `Class`. [Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/kwdkvj).

Comment: @AndyTurner: you are right, it is an internal undocumented class... One must guess that it implements `ParameterizedType` and then use `getRawType()` to find a true Class.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: That's the point. `Type` can be an instance of `Class`, or it can be an instance of `ParameterizedType`, `TypeVariable`, `WildcardType`, or `GenericArrayType`. The latter 4 are interfaces; the implementing class is not relevant.

Comment: Don't forget:

`All Known Subinterfaces: GenericArrayType, ParameterizedType, TypeVariable<D>, WildcardType`

Also don't forget that you can anonymously implement an interface anywhere -- so there may in fact be many classes that implement these interfaces.

In practice, other implementations of Type are obtained by calling e.g. `field.getGenericType()`.

Answer (score -5):

Did you mean this?

```
public <T extends Type> void oneMethod(T clazz) {

}

public void someMethod(Type type) {
    oneMethod(type);
}
```

Comment: You are just moving the problem to inside the method