# How to check if the type is instanceof an interface in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, instanceof

I have a `class` (`CreateAccountRequest`) that implement an `interface`(`Iloggable`), the interface has no method, Just for marking purpose.

```
public interface Iloggable {}    

public class CreateAccountRequest implements Iloggable{
 //some private fields, getters and setters
}
```

In my custom `RequestBodyAdviceAdapter` class, trying to check if the request is an instance of Iloggable, to proceed or ignore the request (for instance do the logging or not )

I know we can use `instanceOf` operator to check if an object implements an interface or not and the unit test as below approve it:

```
@Test
void CreateAccountRequest_Object_Instance_Of_Iloggable_Test() {
    CreateAccountRequest request = new CreateAccountRequest();
    assertTrue(request instanceof Iloggable);
}
```

But in RequestBodyAdviceAdapter supports method the result is false or true all the time, I tried different ways to distinguish if the parameter implement the interface or not

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomRequestBodyAdviceAdapter extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter {
@Override
public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
    //if(methodParameter.getParameterType().isInstance(Iloggable.class)) //return false all the time
    //if(methodParameter.getParameter().getType().isInstance(Iloggable.class))// return false all the time
    if(methodParameter.getParameter().getClass().isInstance(Iloggable.class))// return false all the time
    // if(type instanceof Iloggable)// return false all the time
    //if(type.getClass().isInstance(Iloggable.class)) //return true all the time
    //if(type != null && Iloggable.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getClass()))//return false all the time
      return true;
    return false;
}
    //other override methods
}
```

For removing any doubt, I put a snapshot of the debugging in the support method:

[image]

Comment: I don't think Type will be an instance of any object. Can you share a snippet of how this method is called?

Comment: Type is the class, not an instance. You can't use instanceof on the type, you need to check if the type implements the interface. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `type` is a `java.lang.reflect.Type` (instance) and not an `CreateAccountRequest` (instance;)

You could get more lucky with:

```
if (type instanceof Class) { // type != null
  Class<?> aClazz = (Class<?>) type;
  return Iloggable.class.isAssignableFrom(aClazz);
}
```

[`Class.isAssignableFrom(...)`-javadoc-17](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class))

[Type -> Class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761968/592355)

In depth:

- ```
  if(type instanceof Iloggable) //always false, because type is the
  // (java.lang.reflect.)Type(->class) (occasionally) of the Iloggable and not/ever an instance of it.
  ```
- ```
  if(type.getClass().isInstance(Iloggable.class)) //equivalent to 
  // java.lang.reflect.Type.class.isInstance(Iloggable.class)
  // always false, except when Iloggable *implements* Type (pervert, but possible!;)
  ```
- ```
  Iloggable.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getClass()) //incorporates 
  // my "wrong assumptions" on type... type.getClass() would 
  // evaluate to java.lang.reflect.Type.class, which is similar to bullet 2
  ```

But I assume (when correctly used -> experiment) some [MethodParameter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/MethodParameter.html) methods should also lead to the desired. Especially:

- [`getParameterType()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/MethodParameter.html#getParameterType--)
- [`getGenericParameterType()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/MethodParameter.html#getGenericParameterType--)

Comment: Thanks , I tryied:  type != null && Iloggable.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getClass()), it return false all the time. isAssignableFrom(type) doesn't compile

Comment: sry...my bad: `type` is *not a class*! ..but it holds obviously its name! ..i update my answer!

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to update the answer, I don't see any changes ;)

Comment: check now, plz! ;)

Comment: That worked, Could you please add more explanation to your answer, especially the reason why my other solutions ( updated question) didn't work, so I could accept your brilliant answer?

Comment: ..for the `methodParameter.*`, i would also like to debug ;)...but the `type*` approaches are easy!

Comment: see, update, thx4accept!+1;)

Answer (score 2):

You want to make sure that type represents a class that implements Illoggable.

```
@Override
public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
    if ( type instanceof Class ) {
        cls = ( Class ) type;
        result = Iloggable.class.isAssignableFrom( cls );
    } else {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following comparison, target.getTypeName()==Iloggable.class.getTypeName()